# When install build from xcode push notification is working but when install ipa it is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I implemented push notification in my app and it is working when i install build from xcode but not working when i install app via a link generated by diawi.com why this is happening?

Comment: in device u get the permission first or not when u install the ipa

Comment: diawi.com only used deliver the ipa file to device only  so don't consider this

Comment: ok , I get permission.

Comment: r u get  the device token

Comment: yes i get the device token.

Comment: Is there any error message you are getting? There are some check points you can follow to debug: 1. Are you able to store device token to the 3rd party server?  2. Is the server getting sendPush request from the device? If yes, you can check the logs on server for error message.

Answer (score 3):

Push apns certificates are different for Development & production

- if you install from **xcode** - It uses **development certificate**
- if install from **diawi.com** - It uses **production certificate**

on parse,com i think you have uploaded .p12 file generated from development certificate.

you have to upload .p12 file of production certificate  & then check.

Comment: I hav uploaded both the development and distribution certificate... not working

Comment: did you selected distribution profile & identities for release in code signing? for uploaded build

Comment: yes, i dont think the issue is with ids and ceritficates, coz if I install it though ipa not just the push notification, contacts is also an issue, if I tap to fetch contacts, app crashes... if I build through cable everything works fine.....

Comment: can you try http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SimplePush.zip
at http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 to send push from command line

Answer (score 1):

As @sadiqxs notice there are two types of certs, and in a comment you can find excelent simplePush code (http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SimplePush.zip).

BUT one often forgotten thing!

Your `deviceToken` **changed** (!!!) while you compile to production (ad-hoc) and deploy from Xcode. What i suggest you to do is:

1. Create both developer and production certificate in developer center (what you already have)
2. Download this simple push app
3. Read your deviceToken for development env and check if it's working
4. `NSLog` the token in method: `-(void)application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`

sample:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
    NSString *dt = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    dt = [dt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",dt");
}
```

5. Check out the device log and read the production token
6. Try with simple push if push got to device

6a) If yes, problem solved

6b) If no, and you receive the push for dev env **for sure** you have an issue with certificates and regenerate them

While you using SimplePush script remember to change url to production (gateway.push.apple.com) from sandbox one.

Answer (score 0):

The site install IPA with ad-hoc distribution.

For ad-hoc push notification, you need to use Apple's production push server, which is **gateway.push.apple.com**.

I think you are using sandbox push server when you install it from Xcode.

Comment: I am sending push through Parse.com and if I install the app through cable, push delivers and if though ipa from diawi.com, no push!!!

Comment: yes, through cable = sandbox servers. IPA file = production push (which you likely haven't configured on parse)

Comment: Is there any way I can test Parse push with my developer certificate?

Answer (score 0):

upload .p12 for production on parse to get notifications on ipa.

Comment: I hav uploaded both the development and distribution certificate... not working

Comment: The issue is certainly with production certificate. Have you created APNs distribution certificate?

Comment: Yes, I have created APNs distribution certificate

Comment: What provisioning profile you are using to create ipa?

Comment: I have created id with push notifications enabled in both development and production, created certificate for ios Developer, APNs developemnt and APNs distribution certificate, added their respective p12 file to Parse, created ad-hoc distribution prov profile and added it to xcode.

Comment: I dont think the issue is with certificates or so, coz I am unable to fetch contacts if build via ipa, working fine if build via xcode...

Comment: you should select the same provisioning profile; The one using the certificate that .p12 file is created of and uploaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94281/discussion-between-ali-and-aaa).

Answer (score 0):

Late to this question, but had a similar troubled experienced so thought I'd share. As @sadiqxs noted:

• if you install from xcode - It uses development certificate

• if install from diawi.com - It uses production certificate

This forms a big problem when you try to debug remote notifications. However, **there is a simple workaround!** The trick is to install an AdHoc build once, which will register the phone using the productions certificate. Then add the following block around your register method (the place in the code where you decided to register a user for notfications).

```
#ifndef DEBUG 

//your code to register for notifications, something along the lines of
    UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

#endif
```

What this will do, is skip the register statement when you run the app on consecutive builds through XCode and thus keep production notifications from coming in!

Hope this helps

Comment: Better late than never, but still... I already added this code

Comment: @AAA are you still having problems?

Comment: yes, i still have the problem... am trying all the possiblities to make it work.. :(

Comment: @AAA that is strange, because I can confirm that this code 100% works. Are you sure you are capturing all the calls to register? After downloading the Application through an Ad-Hoc build, you should no longer make any register calls. To test out if you're blocking all the calls try the following: 1. download from build to confirm notifications work, 2. comment out all the register calls, and load app through XCode, this way there is no way you would no longer receive notifications.

Comment: I solved the issue. It may sound silly but I didnt change any of my codes. The issue was with Xcode 7.1. I uninstalled it and then installed lower version 7.0.1 and then run the same code. All the issues were solved. I dont know what is wrong with 7.1, it is not a beta version!!!