# Parse Push Notification: "Invalid Token: User might have uninstalled the app"

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send the push notification form Parse.com. I have tried sending it from website and through my app.

Basically I am in India and my friend is in California. When I try to deliver the push notification to me, it is delivered. But if I try to do the same for my friend,it is not being delivered...

Both of us have same iOS version, approved push notifications, etc..

I double checked my coding, certificates. Everything is perfect. So I wonder since I am using developer certificate will it only be delivered in my nation? Or what else could be wrong?

I could add my code here, but sending Push from website also delivered only to me but not to him...

I got the following error when I try to send a push only to him.
[image]

I think the issue is I am creating an ipa file of my app and send it to him through diawi.com. I run the app in  y mobile though cable.

If I install the app in my device through ipa link, the push notification is not delivered. So the issue is with diawi.com?

Similar issue: [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364094/when-install-build-from-xcode-push-notification-is-working-but-when-install-ipa)

Comment: Diawi creates an enterprise build, so it is a "production" app; you need a production push notification certificate in Parse or you can use TestFlight to distribute your app

Comment: How can I try push notification for developer certificate from Parse

Comment: As I said, either generate and upload a production certificate or distribute an ad-hoc IPA or use Tesflight

Comment: I am using ad-hoc deployment only, but still, it is not working...

Comment: Ad hoc by sending the ipa directly or through diawi?

Comment: So as I have said twice now, that is a production, enterprise deployment; you will need a production certificate on Parse - you can generate this using the Apple developer portal, otherwise add the target UUID to the provisioning profile in the developer portal and send an ad-hoc IPA directly to the user, or even simpler use TestFlight through iTunesconnect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the issue was in the middle. After a lot of searching I found the answer:

For push notifications in Parse, I have only uploaded my developer certificate and it was working for iOS 8 versions. We recently upgraded to 9 and the push not delivered for ipa.

**I have uploaded distribution certificate** to parse and there you go... Push delivered.

But now I am unable to access contacts in ipa but can access if build via cable... I will look for an answer for this issue.

Comment: Mate. you saved my bacon on this one. Thanks a lot.