# iOS APN not received

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have a strange issue.

The code is the following to registrate notifications:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // PUSH NOTIFICATION

    let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

And to handle notifications:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.alertBody = "TEST"
    application.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
```

When I test this simple code in xcode (with a device, not the simulator), no issue. But when I test it without xcode (just on my phone), the local notification does not appear: no sound, no alert, no badge, nothing.

The issue appears when the app is running in background.

The APN sent are silent notifications.

Any idea to fix it?

## EDIT

I solved it by decreasing to 5 the priority of the silent APN.

Comment: The issue appears when the app is running in background.

Comment: What do you mean test it **without** xcode?

Comment: I mean without debugging. I just run the app on my phone to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the issue, please see my edit.

When you send a silent APN (that means with `content-available` set to `1`), the APN `priority` must be 5 and **not 10**.

Comment: I had the same issue. For silent push, we need priority as 5.

Answer (score 0):

Well when installed via xcode the notifications will work with the development (gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com) url. Exporting it as an ipa (ad-hoc) and installing it manually needed notifications to be sent from the production url **gateway.push.apple.com** (including the production key). So you have to create both the keys, and then you can manage to send notifications with the development url when working on xcode and with the production when installing from exported ipa.

Comment: You mean I need the production certificate for APN? But my app is not in production yet, not in appstore, and signed by a dev certificate.

Comment: You need the production profile and production certificate if you haven't installed the app using Xcode, which I am assuming is not the case here.

Comment: The app is installed using Xcode so I guess I do not need the production profile and production certificate in that case.

Comment: Are you sure you have enabled the appropriate background capabilities in Xcode and can you confirm you are not compiling an ad-hoc build.

Comment: Remote notifications are enabled in background capabilities. How can I check if it is an ad-hoc build?

Answer (score 0):

If you've already run your app once via Xcode then you will have previously stored the token to defaults. Therefore when you run it again registerForRemoteNotifications() is not going to get called as you've wrapped it in that if statement.

You should call registerForRemoteNotifications() every time the app launches (and also don't make the assumption the token is a fixed value, its not, it can change).

Comment: Yes that was my first idea, but I tried to call registerForRemoteNotifications() even if the token is already stored but the issue is still here. Anyway I will assume that the token is not a fixed value, you are really right on this point.

Comment: What type of push are you trying to send i.e. directed to the user or silent push directed to the app? If the latter, have you got your device connected to a power supply? (I know that sounds weird, but believe me there's a reason).

Comment: It is a silent push, and yes the device is connected to a power supply (USB plug of my Macbook).

Answer (score 0):

Your deviceToken will change while you compile to production (ad-hoc) and deploy from Xcode.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33600676/5654848).

Comment: Yes you are right. But I dont think that the deviceToken is the origin of the issue. I removed my if condition to call `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` each time the app is launched but the notification issue is still here.